# Count with like and group by - PGSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

How to use group by with as for the same words that have only different numbers at the end?

> Column primaryLabels is varchar
>
> Some inserts may not contain the ITERATION value, I believe this is a problem

*Tentative*

```
SELECT CASE WHEN primaryLabels LIKE 'ITERATION%'  THEN 'ITERATION'
            ELSE NULL END AS primaryLabels,
            COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM tb_bluesight
GROUP BY CASE WHEN primaryLabels LIKE 'ITERATION%'  THEN 'ITERATION'
              ELSE NULL END
```

*Example of a select in the bluesight table and primarylabels field*

```
|----------------------|
|    primaryLabels     |
|----------------------|
|ITERATION 7, CUSTOMER |
|--------------------- |
|ITERATION 8, CUSTOMER |
|----------------------|
|ITERATION 9, CUSTOMER |
|----------------------|
```

*Output:*

```
|------------------------|
|          Count         |
|------------------------|
|             3          |
|------------------------|
```

*Desired output:*

```
|------------------------|
|    Name     | Count    |
|-------------|----------|
|ITERATION 7  | 1        |
|-------------|------- --|
|ITERATION 8  | 1        |
|-------------|----------|
|ITERATION 9  | 1        |
|------------------------|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want something like this:

```
SELECT (REGEXP_MATCH(primaryLabels, 'ITERATION [0-9]+'))[1] as iteration,
       COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM tb_bluesight
GROUP BY iteration;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c9c1ab00e89ce0fdda5646c27ed1b832) is a db<>fiddle.

That said, storing multiple values in a string is a really, really bad idea.  You should be using a junction table.  Or, at least, storing the values in an array.

Comment: Returned all table values ​​with a count of 1 and showed the 'customers' values

Comment: Example: ITERATION 7 = 12 values ​​within the table

Comment: Some inserts may not contain the ITERATION value, I believe this is a problem

Comment: Thank you very much, I just added 'where like', and everything worked, I'll think of a way to group this data in isolation!

Comment: @LuisHenrique . . . I fixed the answer so the missing iterations are handled more elegantly.

Answer (score 1):

For this sample data you can group by the part of the column up to the `,`:

```
select 
  split_part(primaryLabels, ',', 1) "Name",
  count(*) "Count"
from tb_bluesight
where primaryLabels like 'ITERATION%'
group by "Name"
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fWZ9Y4kWWb9sbH9on7AX4t/1).
Results:

```
| Name        | Count |
| ----------- | ----- |
| ITERATION 7 | 1     |
| ITERATION 8 | 1     |
| ITERATION 9 | 1     |
```